# Trying to figure out how to open a folder in a file manager

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have spent the last 30 minutes trying to figure out how to open a folder in a file manager

This is the code that I have tried:

```
subprocess.Popen('explorer "' + path + '"')  
#and
subprocess.call('explorer "' + path + '"', shell=True)
```

But I get no success. What can I do?

I would like it to be cross platform if possible

Comment: If you run `explorer` it's not going to be cross-platform.

Comment: What if the other platform has no GUI?

Comment: What if he is developing a program for personal use ?

Comment: @PeterWood The program is already GUI based so if they managed to run it up to this point without a GUI then they must be working miracles, but without that knowledge (that you didn't have) your point would be valid

Comment: @KlausD. I know that. My hope was that someone knew of a compatibility layer that would talk to the default file managers on different operating systems.

Comment: @AminGuermazi I appreciate you standing up for me in the comments, but 'personal use' is not a valid excuse to take shortcuts. I have had multiple programs over the years that started out as 'personal use' that ended up being used in production environments

Comment: Oh ok looking for a cross platform way

Comment: @AndrewHarris So what is the cross platform GUI you are using? Update the question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve], particularly regarding the GUI toolkit you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is very simple:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"C:\path\of\folder"')
```

Or if the path is a variable:

```
import subprocess
path = r"C:\path\of\folder"
subprocess.Popen(f'explorer /select,"{path}"')
```

Comment: Both of your solutions work. I found out that my problem was that I was mixing \ and / in my path. Once I fixed that it worked perfectly. I was hoping for a cross platform way of doing it but I'm guessing that the answer is that there isn't one. Thank you so much for your help!